# PHP + MySQL "WHERE ... IN" doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I build my query like this:

```
foreach($ids as $key => $idi) {
    $ids[$key] = "'" . $idi . "'";
};
$ids_imploded = implode(", ", $ids);
$sql = "SELECT record_id, email FROM `actions_attendees` WHERE `action_id` IN (" . $ids_imploded . ") AND `backup` = 1 ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC LIMIT " . count($ids) . ";";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Where `$ids` is just array of few numbers (so the `$ids_imploded = "'132', '165'"`).

When I run the generated query in phpMyAdmin, I get what I want. When I run it from PHP, it returns just object with nulls. Why?

I doesn't work neither if I remove the escaping loop.

EDIT: generated query is echoed like

```
SELECT record_id, email FROM `actions_attendees` WHERE `action_id` IN ('1614', '1615') AND `backup` = 1 ORDER BY `timestamp` ASC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Perhaps have it echo out your SQL statement instead of executing it and insure that it's written as expected.

Comment: I of course did that and ran the echo through phpMyAdmin and it worked

Comment: Show the db connection part

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are querying the wrong database, try select a db first, try executing this before the query :

```
 mysql_select_db('yourdb');
```

Is the result of your query true ? Check your connection object, it seems like you are not on the right database.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the query was indeed working even in PHP, but later when I was processing the results, intellisense tricked me and I was using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`...